# Recursive bijection on $\mathbb{N}^3$ using one on $\mathbb{N}^2$

Tags: functions, logic

I am to find a recursive bijection $f:\mathbb{N}^3\to\mathbb{N}$. I know some solutions, but I would appreciate some comments on the following solutions:

Is it always true that

> Let $g$ be a recursive bijection from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}$, then $$f(m,n,k)=g(k,g(m,n))$$
>   is a recursive bijection from $\mathbb{N}^3$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Therefore I could use for $g$ some know function.

Comment: This is really just verifying definitions of what it means to be a bijection. It's not *very* hard. It's just a bit messy.

Comment: yeah I though so, I only wanted an "inside" confirmation before writing the full proof. thanks

Comment: http://karagila.org/2018/in-praise-of-failure/

Comment: True, I got lazy here. Excellent post BTW